# Monitoring protected login page with zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I'm new to Zabbix and I have some troubles with setting up login monitoring on our site. The issue is that our login form contains some hidden input field called 'lt' with randomly generated string that needs to be submitted along with user data to login successfully. Question is how can I parse page to get the generated value from page and use it to submit form along with traditional login/password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use variable, which will be defined by regexp. For example:

```
{lt}=regex:"lt":"(.+)"
```

Then you can use `lt` variable in next step of your web scenario.

Doc: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/web_monitoring

Comment: Great. I missed the thing with saving webpage content to variables. Other thing that documentation dont mention is that parsing is done at the end of the step so to get data for step 2 you need to define variable with data parsing in step 1.